# What is "perm="elradfmwMT""?

Tags: python, ftp, pyftpdlib

I saw perm="elradfmwMT" in a many demo FTP servers in python. What does it do?

It was at

```
authorizer.add_user(user, pwd, "/", perm="elradfmwMT")
```

Comment: The meaning of those flags is described in the [documentation](https://pyftpdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).

Answer (score 0):

That describes the permissions. As written in the [documentation](https://pyftpdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#users)

**Read permissions:**
"e" = change directory (CWD, CDUP commands)
"l" = list files (LIST, NLST, STAT, MLSD, MLST, SIZE commands)
"r" = retrieve file from the server (RETR command)

**Write permissions:**
"a" = append data to an existing file (APPE command)
"d" = delete file or directory (DELE, RMD commands)
"f" = rename file or directory (RNFR, RNTO commands)
"m" = create directory (MKD command)
"w" = store a file to the server (STOR, STOU commands)
"M" = change file mode / permission (SITE CHMOD command) New in 0.7.0
"T" = change file modification time (SITE MFMT command) New in 1.5.3